# Async/Await differentiate reject from error

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, try-catch

I've been reading about the use of `async/await` instead of the classic `.then()` in Promises, but there's still something that I don't understand.

I know that you can replace the classic `.then().catch()` with `async/await` and `try and catch` but that will handle `exceptions` and `rejects` like they're the same.

Example:

```js
async function func1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //throw new Error("error");
        reject("rejected"); 
    });
}

async function func2() {
    try {
        const message = await func1();
        console.log(message);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

func2();
```

Both `reject` and `throw new Error` will fall into the `catch` block but Promises also has the next sintaxis:

`then(funcResolve, funcReject).catch(funcCatch)` but `async/await` treats both `reject` and `errors` as the same.

Is there any way to differentiate with `async/await` an `error` from a `reject`?

Comment: You have a few options. One is to wrap every asynchronous operation in your `async/await` with it's own try/catch and possibly modify your error there. You could make your asynchronous functions potentially throw custom errors. If the async operations are network requests, the errors produced there will potentially have properties that non-network errors have, so you can possibly check for that

Comment: `.catch(func)` is just a shortcut for `.then(undefined, func)`. Promises themselves don't distinguish between "rejected because it called the reject function" and "rejected because of an exception"

Comment: `then(funcResolve, funcReject).catch(funcCatch)` -- I believe that in that code, `funcCatch` would ONLY catch errors thrown in `funcReject`, not errors thrown by the promise or errors thrown in `funcResolve`

Comment: (edit) ACTUALLY I'm wrong. `promise.then(funcResolve, funcReject).catch(funcCatch)` behaves differently than I expect. A rejection from `promise` goes to `funcReject`, while an error thrown in `funcResolve` skips `funcReject` and goes straight to `funcCatch`. At least in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Based on a small amount of experimentation in Chrome, it looks like `promise().then(funcResolve, funcReject).catch(funcCatch)` is **nearly** functionally equivalent to

```
async function run() {
  try {
    try {
      const result = await promise();
    } catch(e) {
      // funcReject code here
    }
    // funcResolve code here
  } catch(e) {
    // funcCatch code here
    // this catches errors generated in funcReject and funcResolve
  }
}
```

The only difference is, in the promise version, funcResolve doesn't run after funcReject but in my async code it does.

You can still achieve the same sorts of results if you absolutely need to distinguish between errors from async operations and error from synchronous operations. You can make sure your async operations return a custom class that extends Error, for example, and check for the class in your catch

```
class AsyncError extends Error{}
// in your async code, make sure you transform all errors into AsyncErrors

try { promise() } catch(e) { 
    if (e instanceof AsyncError) {} else {}
}
```